# Character set and collate doesn't appear on column definition of a create table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have this strange issue.

In MySQL 5.7.18 installed in an Ubuntu server 16.04 I create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`SURNAME` varchar(108) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `SURNAME` (`SURNAME`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT=' (Enc.)'
```

But, if I execute this instruction:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE test;
```

I don't see the character set and the collate that I have defined in the CREATE TABLE instruction.

Apparently, there aren't error or warning after creation finish.

Currently, I have set the character set of the database to utf8 and the collation to utf8_general_ci

Anyone know the why of this behavior? And if yes, What I can do to solve this issue?

P.S.: Don't kill me if this post is a duplicate or something else.

Thanks at all.

Lorenzo.

**UPDATE**

I have made another test. If I use a different collation (utf8_bin) with a different character set (utf8) with SHOW CREATE TABLE I can see the definition that I have used in the instruction for create the table.

Now, I have this new question. The character set and collation in the column definition must be different (eg. utf8 and utf8_bin) to appears?

Thanks again.

Lorenzo.

Answer (score 1):

Lorenzo,

The reason you do not see the collation you specified is due to the fact that you specified a default collation for the character set. Each character set has one default collation. You went to the extra effort of specifying collation (utf8_general_ci), the default for utf8. Had you specified collation (utf8_unicode_ci) for example, you would see it during your SHOW command.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `lang_test` (
`mystr` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `lang_test2` (
`mystr` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-table.html)?

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_name (column_list)
[[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]
[COLLATE collation_name]]
```

It is `CHARACTER SET` name.

You can specify only one of them and the other is set by default.

Comment: Hi @Rares Abrudan. Thanks. But, my problem is on the columns definition after I have created the table. If I check the created table (SHOW CREATE TABLE), it doesn't contains the definitions that I have defined within CREATE TABLE instruction.